# loading the source of a BitmapImage in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

In a silverlight app, I have a BitmapImage defined as `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` and it as a method called "`SetSource`" where I can set the source like this:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
System.IO.Stream stream = _scene.GetStream();
if (stream == null) return;
bitmap.SetSource(stream);
```

In a WPF application I have also have a 
Bitmap image defined as `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` but there is no SetSource method.  How do I set the source in a WPF app like I do in a Silverlight app?

Also, it is a stream, not a string.  It is not a URI.  so "UriSource" method does not work.  I tried this:

```
        System.IO.Stream stream = _scene.GetStream();
        if (stream == null) return;
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(stream.ToString());
```

And at runtime, it threw an error tha URI cannot be determined.  Is the URI an identifier for the intranet?  Are you sure that this is not a silverlight thing?  I am doing a WPF application

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to set the [BitmapImage.StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource) property:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = _scene.GetStream();
bitmap.EndInit();
```

If you want to close the stream right after creating the bitmap, you would also have to set the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` option:

```
using (Stream stream = _scene.GetStream())
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473.aspx) to specify the [UriSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(uriSource: new Uri());
```

Or you can use [BitmapImage.StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) property to set the StreamSource